# How to deploy storage account using classical deployment model

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cli

I am wondering how to deploy storage accounts in Azure via PowerShell using the classical deployment model and NOT ARM deployment.

I know we can use [New-AzStorageAccount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/new-azstorageaccount?view=azps-7.3.2) but I think it uses ARM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that `New-AzStorageAccount` uses ARM. You can create a classic storage account using a really old version of Azure PowerShell Cmdlets that support classic deployment model.

Another way to create a classic storage account is to use [`New-AzResource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azresource?view=azps-7.3.2) Cmdlet. I used the following script to create a classic storage account:

```
$location = "West US" #Location of the storage account

$name = "mystorageaccount" #Name of the storage account

$accountType = "Standard_RAGRS" #Account type (RAGRS, LRS, GRS etc.)

$resourceType = "Microsoft.ClassicStorage/storageAccounts" #Storage account resource type

$resourceGroupName = "myresourcegroup" #Resource group name

New-AzResource -Location $location -Properties @{AccountType=$accountType} -ResourceName $name -ResourceType $resourceType -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Force -Verbose
```

Comment: do you know how to deploy a VM using `New-AzResource`?

Comment: You mean Classic VM?

Comment: Can you please help with question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77049141/how-to-do-get-msaltoken-in-c-sharp