# How to do Get-MsalToken in C#

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-sdk-.net

I can get a bearer token using these parameters `Get-MsalToken -ClientId '' -TenantId '' -Scopes ''`

I am trying to convert it to use C# instead of PowerShell:

```cs
var clientId = "xyz";
var tenantId = "xyz";

// We intend to obtain a token for Graph for the following scopes (permissions)
string[] scopes = { $"{clientId}/.default" };

string authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}";

IPublicClientApplication app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
    .WithAuthority(new Uri(authority))
    .WithRedirectUri("http://localhost")
    .Build();

AuthenticationResult result = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
var token =  result.AccessToken;
```

But I get an error saying: "The redirect URI 'http://localhost' specified in the request does not match the redirect URIs configured for the application"

Comment: have you tried your code without using `.WithRedirectUri("http://localhost")`?

Comment: Same error unfortunately

Comment: Check this out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.applicationoptions.redirecturi?view=msal-dotnet-latest, here it says while trying to get the token in .NET, you need to add `RedirectUri` but in case of Get-MsalToken, its using MSAL.PS module which wraps MSAL.NET functionality into PowerShell-friendly cmdlets, refer https://github.com/AzureAD/MSAL.PS.

Answer (score -1):

This is happening because your app in Azure is not configured to redirect to `localhost`. You need to update it in Azure portal. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/active-directory/error-code-aadsts50011-redirect-uri-mismatch

Comment: I know but I am not specifying any redirect uri to `Get-MsalToken`, why it works? under the hood, they both use the same nuget package.

Comment: If you are not providing `redirectUri` in PowerShell, try `.WithDefaultRedirectUri()` instead of `.WithRedirectUri("http://localhost")`

Comment: More about `RedirectUri`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-client-application-configuration#redirect-uri

Comment: same error unfortunately